# Is memory for CLR SSIS module included in the memory reserved for SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, clr, memory-pressure

I have many issues like this in my SQL Server 2017:

> ---
>
> ### Mensaje
> AppDomain 16 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].26) is marked for unload due to memory >pressure.

Should I increase or reduce the "max memory" parameter?

More generally, is the memory for CLR SSIS module included in the memory reserved for SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general, CLR seems to be managed by max_server_memory setting since SQL Server 201x (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-2017#dynamic-memory-management), so yse it's included. What's your memory configuration, how much memory there is on the server, what are the memory settings in SQL Server and are there other components running on the same server?

Comment: Thanks, Gigga. If you make an answer from your comment I will accept it as the answer.